# What is a function called that maps the minimum of the domain to the minimum of the codomain?

Tags: functions, terminology, order-theory, maxima-minima

Is there a standard name for a function that maps the minimum of the domain to the minimum of the codomain?

In greater detail, let $\mathbf{X} = (X,\leq)$ and $\mathbf{Y} = (Y, \leq)$ be partially-ordered spaces. Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ each has a minimum. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Is there a name, known in the mathematical literature, for the following property of $f$: $ f(\min \mathbf{X}) = \min\mathbf{Y}$?

Comment: Do you assume other properties on f?

Comment: @AlonYariv: No, but if you are familiar with a property that includes, among other things, the property described in my question, please let me know.

Comment: A monotone (increasing) function that is also onto/surjective would do this.

Comment: @MarkS.: True. What if the function is not surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the phrase "minimum-preserving" for such functions, but would define what that means in context. The phrase is used in other mathematical texts*, although I couldn't find one using precisely this definition.

*See the book ["Cooperative Control of Dynamical Systems: Applications to Autonomous Vehicles" by Zhihua Qu](https://books.google.com/books?id=_oRTeVWCuSsC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=%22minimum-preserving%22&source=bl&ots=DLVPazl-8C&sig=ACfU3U1DVvd8LQDdBxoxElsitAP-D0ebdw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7__yO1bHrAhUQl3IEHZ4hBzQQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22minimum-preserving%22&f=false), the blog post ["The Smooth-Max Minimum Incident of December 2018" by Erik Erlandson](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2019/01/02/the-smooth-max-minimum-incident-of-december-2018/), and the MathOverflow post [Minimum Preserving Transformations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310076/28209).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks!